# prolog - findall sort and return the first

Tags: prolog

I have some facts like:

```
motherboard('name', price, 'price range', score).
```

I need to take the best motherboard by score, so I guess I should use findall but I'm not understanding how to order by score(desc order) and take the first! Could you help me please?

EDIT - @user27815 solution:

```
motherboard('Gigabyte B360M Aourus Gaming 3', 86, 'low_range', 3).
motherboard('MSI B350M Mortar', 93, 'low_range', 4).
motherboard('ASUS ROG Strix B350\u002DF', 114, 'middle_range', 6).
motherboard('MSI Z370 Tomahawk', 139, 'middle_range', 7).
motherboard('Gigabyte Aorus AX370 Gaming K7', 169, 'high_range', 8).

setof(Score-Nome,motherboard(Nome, Price,Price_range, Score),Pairs), sort(1,@>,Pairs,Sorted),
        write(Pairs),
        nl,
        write(Sorted).
```

The result is: [3-Gigabyte B360M Aourus Gaming 3] for both Pairs and Sorted, it ends withoud dot and I can press ; to have more solutions, why is it not printing them all together? And anyway the order is the same for pairs and sorted

@PauloMoura solution-
With the same data of the previous solution:
setof(Score-Nome,motherboard(Nome, Price, Price_range, Score),Pairs), last(Pairs, BestMotherboard),
        write(BestMotherboard).

I get this:

```
?- start.
3-Gigabyte B360M Aourus Gaming 3
true ;
4-MSI B350M Mortar
true ;
6-ASUS ROG Strix B350-F
true ;
7-MSI Z370 Tomahawk
true ;
8-Gigabyte Aorus AX370 Gaming K7
true.
```

Comment: You need to use `setof(Score-Nome,Price^Price_range^motherboard(Nome, Price,Price_range, Score),Pairs), sort(1,@>,Pairs,Sorted),
        write(Pairs),
        nl,
        write(Sorted).`
So that the Price and Price range are ignored in the setof call.

Comment: As @user27815 noted, you need to explicitly qualify the arguments in the `setof/3` second argument that you want to ignore. That will give you a single solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
motherboard('thing1', price, 'price range', 5).
motherboard('thing2', price, 'price range', 4).
motherboard('thing3', price, 'price range', 3).
motherboard('thing4', price, 'price range', 2).
motherboard('thing5', price, 'price range', 1).
```

We can query:

```
?-setof(Score-Thing,motherboard(Thing,price,'price range',Scores),Pairs), sort(1,@>,Pairs,Sorted).
Pairs = [1-thing5, 2-thing4, 3-thing3, 4-thing2, 5-thing1],
Sorted = [5-thing1, 4-thing2, 3-thing3, 2-thing4, 1-thing5].
```

`setof/3` sorts the answers but not in the order you want, so we need to use `sort/4` if we want the whole list sorted rather than just the topscore.

Alternatively you could define an inverse predicate (make 5 into -5 etc) and include that in the `setof/3` call to avoid 'sorting twice' but you would then need to reinvert the sorted list to see the original numbers, this wont work if anything has a negative score.

Comment: If you are sorting after collecting, then maybe collect without sorting using `findall/3`?

Comment: @user27815 I've edited the first post with the result of your solution

Comment: @Paulo Moura For the first solution outlined that is true and a good point, but in the second which I did not detail you would use `setof/3` still.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that `sort/4` is neither a standard predicate nor a common library predicate.

Answer (score 2):

Using instead the standard `setof/3` predicate instead of the `findall/3` predicate will give you a list sorted in ascending order. You can then traverse that list to take the last element, which will be the motherboard with the best score. Something like:

```
...,
setof(..., ..., Motherboards),
last(Motherboards, BestMotherboard).
```

The `last/2` predicate is a common library predicate.

Comment: How is this list ordered by score? Anyway I'm trying with this:

    setof(motherboard(Nome), motherboard(Name, Price, Price_range, Score), Motherboards),
  last(Motherboards, BestMotherboard).
  write(BestMotherboard),

but I get this error for the write:  Full stop in clause-body?  Cannot redefine ,/2

Comment: @Nicola You have a `.` after the call to `last/2`.

Comment: right, but there's still something wrong, the system returned false

Comment: @Nicola Your first argument to the `setof/3` call must contain the score so that you can get a list sorted by the scores. E.g. `Score-Name`.